# metasploit confusion

Tags: windows, networking, exploit

I'm using (Metasploit framework-3.4.0-linux-i686) under Kubuntu, and i'm the only Linux machine connected to my company network, so i was trying to let my boss know that our network is a big mess, and prove that using metasploit, witch i didn't use before just heared the guys talking about it a year ago.

though using Metasploit is pretty easy, but non of the exploits is working properly, and when ever i write `exploit` on the `msconsole` it gives me something like "exploit executed but no session was created.", and i'm pretty sure i'm doing the configuration right, i even checked that twice a every time i change the exploit.

BTW our main network depends on a 2 Windows server 2003 machines.

any ideas ??? am i doing this wrong ????

Comment: How do you know it's a big mess?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your environment is like, and this doesn't answer your question, but have you considered that it's not a good idea to be using an exploit framework you don't fully understand against a production network?

To your question, [from H D Moore at the Metasploit mailing list](http://seclists.org/metasploit/2007/q2/332):

> The "no session was created" message
>   occurs if one of the following 
>   happens:
>
> 1) The exploit you use doesn't work
>   against the target you selected. Could
>   be the exploit is for a different
>   version, there is a problem with the 
>   exploit code, or there is a problem
>   with the target configuration.
>
> 2) The exploit you use was configured
>   to use a payload that doesn't create 
>   an interactive session. In this case,
>   the framework has no way of knowing 
>   whether the exploited worked, because
>   it doesn't receive a connection  from
>   the target when its successful (for
>   example, running notepad).
>   [...]